# What are all the scripting languages that can be used for Jenkins CI?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to clarify all the possible languages that can be used inside Jenkins. From what I have seen from the website, it seems there are only a few possibilities: python, groovy, bash, and ruby. Are these correct and are these all of them?

Comment: There is shell support in jenkins.. So if you have interpreter of any script you can use it with jenkins

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins supports tons of scripting languages. Any scripting language supported by OS will be runnable from Jenkins as long it does not interact with desktop.  So bash, windows scripting, powershell etc  good to use.

While not really a "scripting" language, you can run maven builds directly. So is the case with [Jenkins Gradle plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin)

If for some reason you want more control, you can extend Jenkins using Java/Groovy etc:  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extend+Jenkins